# grid-column doesn't work?

Tags: css, css-grid

I have this markup

```
<main>
<section class="download">
  <img src="media/icon.svg" alt="TOX chat icon" width="345" height="280">
  <div class="download_desc">
    <h1>A New Kind of Instant Messaging</h1>
    <p>
      Whether it's corporations or governments, digital surveillance today is widespread. Tox is easy-to-use software that connects
      you with friends and family without anyone else listening in. While other big-name services require you to pay
      for features, Tox is completely free and comes without advertising — forever.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

and CSS applied:

```
    main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 750px 500px 815px 815px 180px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.download {
  background-color: #414141;
  color: white;
}

.download_desc {
  grid-column: 2/6;
}
```

For some reason, grid-column at this case doesn't work at all.
`div` with `download_desc` class is still in the first column, not from 2nd to 6th as I wanted.

It works if i apply it directly to the `.download` class, but not it's children.

Why?

Comment: Note: i'm currently trying to copy homepage of TOX chat (tox.chat) for practice, so don't mind the content. All credit for that goes to them.

Comment: "Doesn't work" is not a technical term. What doesn't work? And, in your title, why are you asking us if it works or not?

Comment: @Rob it doesn't do what it has to. In this case, div with class "download_desc" is not placed from 2nd to 6th column of the grid. It's all still in the first one.

Comment: Put that information in  your question, not here in the comments, but "doesn't do what it has to" is just as bad as "doesn't work".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that your grid is the 'main' element and 'download_desc' is within the 'download' section tag.

Try moving:

```
display: grid;
grid-template-rows: 750px 500px 815px 815px 180px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
```

to the 'download' class.

Comment: Does that mean, that if i want to use grid through all of the page, i have to apply `display: grid` to each section?

Comment: You can arrange your page into grids and sub-grids. For an element to be positioned within a grid its parent must be a grid.

Comment: You could for example layout your sections using grids and then create sub-grids in the sections to align their content.

Answer (score 1):

You have applied `grid` css in the `main` which means `.download` is a grid item...means applying `grid-column` in `download_desc` will do nothing...it useless....`grid-column` property is for the `grid-item` not for the inner elements of `grid-item`.

Apply `grid` css to the `.download` which will make the `<img>` and the `download_desc` grid item.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
.download {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 750px 500px 815px 815px 180px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
}

.download {
  background-color: #414141;
  color: white;
}

.download_desc {
  grid-column: 2 / span 5;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section class="download">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="TOX chat icon">
    <div class="download_desc">
      <h1>A New Kind of Instant Messaging</h1>
      <p>
        Whether it's corporations or governments, digital surveillance today is widespread. Tox is easy-to-use software that connects you with friends and family without anyone else listening in. While other big-name services require you to pay for features,
        Tox is completely free and comes without advertising — forever.
      </p>
    </div>
  </section>
</main>
```