# How can I solve this error? css grid-column

Tags: css, css-grid

I try to make grid column,but the property don't diplay,and its said invalid property value.

Can you help me solver this error?

```
    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(to left, #ba7463, #d1a984);
  z-index: -1;
}

nav {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 10% 1fr 1fr 10%;
  min-height: 10vh;
  color: white;
}
#logo {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

here is my css file.

And there is the error:

[image: Error]

Comment: are you using SASS by any chance?

Comment: No,Im using LESS,but when I see your question,I find the solution: I need to change grid-column : 2/3 to grid-column ~"2/3"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [grid-column doesn't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48686526/grid-column-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
#logo {
    /*grid-column: 2/3;*/
    grid-column-start: 2;
    grid-column-end: 3;
    font-size: 24px;
}
```